# How to get the value of variable unchanged on nested function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I m doing a validation script. And , i want to know the current status of my validator tab using the following but the the variable **isValid** unable to get its recent value on below function.

```
$('#btn_store_next_page').click( function() {

   $isValid = false;

 //check the validity of the current tabs being validted status
$somefunction.on('status.field.bv',function(e, data,$isValid) {                                
         $isValid = true;
 });   
console.log($isValid); //prints false so how to access as true like above      
}
```

**EditNote:**
I have referenced the as $isValid not isValid.

Comment: Why is there a `$` before isValid when you first set it? Then in your console log it's not there

Comment: Guys , i have used a uniform access using all $isValid , no result.

Comment: deliberately yes  inside function. Are refering to this $isValid = false; on above function >

Comment: Can you make a fiddle? I think I know what you want to do but would rather test with code than guess

Comment: i have make the question simpler to understand ,how about now ?

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring the variable global outside the function:

```
$('#btn_store_next_page').click( function() {

  var $isValid = false; // var

  //check the validity of the current tabs being validted status
  $somefunction.on('status.field.bv',function(e, data,$isValid){                                
     $isValid = true;
  });   
  console.log($isValid); //prints false so how to access as true like above      
}
```

Comment: nah , there must be by reference thing :(

Answer (score 0):

Answered finally .

using the following :

```
 $('#btn_store_next_page').click( function() {
       var self = this;


           $(function () {
             self.value = 'xxxx';

          });
           console.log(self.value);                                                 

    });
```